# Circular dependency with Angular 2 and SystemJS

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I have a problem that I think is caused by a circular dependency. After some extensive research, I haven't been able to find a solution. It looks related to this issue : [TypeError: b is undefined in __extends](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4341) in TypeScript, but it didn't help me.

I have been able to simplify the problem in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qWEdfEWIaSD2cCaeJ6JX).

Basically there are 3 classes :

- the class `A`, that contains an array of `A`
- the class `B`, that inherits from `A`
- the class `F`, a factory that can create an `A` or a `B` depending on a value

The purpose of this is to handle a parameter list that can be dynamic (each `A` is a parameter and can be an array) and where `B` is a specialization of `A` to handle files. I tried removing the factory, but with only `A` and `B` I still get the same error :

`TypeError: b is undefined
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`

Here is the code of **a.ts**

```
import { F } from './f';

export class A {
  children: A[]

  constructor(hasChildren: boolean = false) {
    if (hasChildren) {
      for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        let isB = (Math.random() * 2) > 1;
        this.children.push(F.createObject(isB))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**b.ts**

```
import { A } from './a';

export class B extends A {
}
```

and **f.ts**

```
import { A } from './a'
import { B } from './b'

export class F {
  static createObject(isB: boolean): A {
    if (isB) {
      return new B
    } else {
      return new A
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the line containing the `b` mentioned in the error message?

Comment: In the javascript console. Actually if the classes are named `toto` and `tata` the error message is still `TypeError: b is undefined
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`

Comment: The Plunker link doesn't work for me.

Comment: For me neither... I'll change the link in 2 minutes, I'm doing a plunker without the factory.

Comment: I just updated it, the link should be working.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate (see above). See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6516

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of the link above. Simply putting the two classes in the same file worked, thanks. Here is the working plunker if it can help : http://plnkr.co/edit/fi2MAGeA7MjdqewZcyjb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a circular dependency this way. You can work around by using an interface

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHo434GcFRcdSHbk3aLa?p=preview)

**tata.ts**

```
import { IToto } from './itoto';


export class Tata implements IToto {
  children: Toto[]
}
```

**toto.ts**

```
import { Tata } from './tata';
import { IToto } from './itoto';

export class Toto implements IToto{
  children: Toto[] = [];

  constructor(hasChildren: boolean = false) {
     ...
  }
}
```

**itoto.ts**

```
export interface IToto {
  children: Toto[]
}
```

See also [Circular dependency injection angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525850/circular-dependency-injection-angular-2)

Comment: I don't get it - itoto imports itself?

Comment: yeah this is confusing, not getting it either...

Comment: I have posted an answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/41807260/6903440