# Services depending on each other

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 app, I have two services that depend on each other (service A calling methods from service B and vice versa).

Here are the relevant code:

`app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {TempService} from '../services/tmp';
import {Temp2Service} from '../services/tmp2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app/app.component.html',
    providers: [TempService, Temp2Service]
})
export class AppComponent { (...) }
```

Service 1:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Temp2Service} from './tmp2';

@Injectable()
export class TempService {
  constructor (private _sessionService: Temp2Service) {}
}
```

Service 2:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {TempService} from './tmp';

@Injectable()
export class Temp2Service {
  constructor (private _sessionService: TempService) {}
}
```

Running the app leads to the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for
>   'Temp2Service'(undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are
>   decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that
>   'Temp2Service' is decorated with Injectable

When commenting the constructor in one of the services, the app runs fine. So my guess is that the "cross-reference" of the two services is causing the problem.

Do you have an idea what is going wrong here? Or is my approach already wrong?

Comment: Well, angular needs a TempService to construct a Temp2Service, and it needs a Temp2Service to construct a TempService. It's a chicken and egg problem. Create a third service, and delegate to this third service to break the dependency.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a called circular dependency. It is not an issue with Angular2 itself. It is not allowed in any language I am aware of.

You will need to refactor your code to remove this circular dependency. Likely you will need to breakup one of these services into new service.

If you follow the single responsibility principle you will find you won't get into circular dependency trap.

Comment: Actually, circular dependencies are allowed in all languages I know of. The problem is that the dependencies are needed by the constructor. If they were not, you could do `let a = new A(); let b = new B(); a.b = b; b.a = a;`. You would still have a circular dependency, but everything would run fine. I'm NOT saying that circular dependencies are a good thing. Just saying that they're possible.

Comment: In some cases circular dependency can't be avoided. I found Julian FARHI's answer referencing forward reference useful. Solved my problem.

Comment: `forwardRef` is for circular dependencies of classes within the same file. My answer is about DI dependencies. `forwardRef` won't have any influence of circular constructor dependencies of injectables. Removing one dependency from the constructor to break the cycle and instead inject `Injector` and use `setTimeout(() => { this.someDep = injector.get(SomeDependency); }` would be a way to work around.

Comment: my answer provides a specific  option for how to solve this

Comment: "In you follow the single responsibly principle you will find you won't get into circular dependency trap." This seems like a false statement. I have a view that can be shown as part of the page, or shown as a modal dialog. My view shows related models, which you can click on to view in a modal dialog. In Angular's eyes, this creates a circular dependency (the modal is not injected into the constructor). The responsibility of the actual view is no different in both scenarios (show the model), but it creates a circular dependency. I appreciate my scenario is different to the question, however.

Comment: You do not need to refactor your code. Just do not use constructor based injection. Use explicit injection. Why is this the top answer?

Comment: this response don't answer the question, the most simple solution is provided by @CharlesRobertson

Comment: I dislike that  ts has so huge problems with circular dependencies.
circular dependecies are just really bad for Serializing.
I used this very often. If you have a lot of services that manage things globally as a singleton, this is a very powerful tool and its a pity that they "fixed" this angularJS feature.

Answer (score 45):

Constructor injection prevents circular dependencies.

It can be broken up by injecting the `Injector` and requesting a dependency imperatively like:

```ts
private payrollService:PayrollService;
constructor(/*private payrollService:PayrollService*/ injector:Injector) {
  setTimeout(() => this.payrollService = injector.get(PayrollService));
}
```

See also [Circular dependency injection angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525850/circular-dependency-injection-angular-2)

Comment: What do you expect? Constructor injection can't work with circular dependencies. The only good option is to get rid of the circle.

Comment: `this.payrollService = this.injector.get<ICustomInterface>('PayrollService')` should be good enough I think. Not sure if `setTimeout...` is necessary.

Comment: Yes, setTimeout is necessary, otherwise you still have the cycle.

Comment: oh ok. I didn't have to add `setTimeout` to get it to work because I initialized it in a function outside of the constructor.

Comment: I get this error even if I place the `injector.get` call in a method that is NEVER called.  Angular CLI - not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Perhaps another problem. I'd suggest a new question with a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: There is nothing that has changed. Try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com then others can investigate

Answer (score 35):

The key here is not to inject the service via the constructor, but instead, use explicit setters & getters. I would use the following pattern in Angular 4:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { FooService } from './foo/foo.service';
import { BarService } from './bar/bar.service';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public fooService: FooService, public barService: BarService) {

    this.fooService.setBarService(barService);

  }

}
```

**foo.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {

    barService: any;

    constructor(){
    }

    setBarService(barService: any): void {
        this.barService = barService;
    }

    getBarService(): any {
        return this.barService;
    }

}
```

Comment: based in the KISS principle, should be considered the right answer

Comment: @Dimas Crocco Thanks for the comment. I agree. It's good to provide theory, but at the end of the day, the OP wants a concrete example, which I feel I gave him.

Comment: Thank you for following the spirit of Stack Overflow and actually providing an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I updated this solution to work with Angular > 4. Using Injector class you can inject a service into another service

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { TempService } from './tmp';


@Injectable()
export class Temp2Service {

  private tempService: any;

  constructor (private injector: Injector) { }

  public funcA() {
     this.tempService = this.injector.get(TempService);
     this.tempService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not help in Angular 4.0.

Comment: This is playing with fire - avoid it :)

Comment: @AlexanderMills: why do you say it is playing with fire ? and what better solution do you have ? Thank you.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution to an unreasonable problem.

Comment: This actually still works in later versions. Is it playing with fire? Yes, because it works around DI and will mess with testing. However, when you have a circular reference that is not glaringly obvious and is costing you production time and devs are sitting on their hands, this is a work-around to get your developers moving again while one person dives deep and tries to figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

It's a circular dependency and unfortunately it's a fundamental computer science problem, or information problem, something that Angular cannot solve. Try doing something like this instead:

```js
export class ServiceA {
 constructor(private b: ServiceB){
    b.setA(this);
 }
}

export class ServiceB {
 
 private a: ServiceA

 constructor(){
    
 }

 setA(a){
   this.a = a;
 }

}
```

that's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: A simple and thus fast solution to an annoying problem. Props.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve forwordRef function to solve this issue.

//Allows to refer to references which are not yet defined.

@Inject(forwardRef(() => MyService)) private httpProxy: MyService

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 2, and need circular dependency for calling functions of each other on some events, you may use Observables and subscribe them in Service in which you injected the other service.

Example:

```js
@Injectable()
class Service1 {

  observeEvents() {
    return Obsevable.create((o) => {
      //store `o` it in any class variable
      //whenever you want to call function of Service2 from this class, do this `o.next('method_name');`
    });
  }
}

@Injectable()
class Service2 {
  constructor(private service1: Service1) {
    this.service1.subscribe((method) => {
      this[method]();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I won't downvote because all of these are hacks (thanks, Angular2, for not providing proper decorators) -- but this -- this is a hack. Props to the alternative solution, though.

Comment: @Cody sir, are hacks not allowed?

Comment: Yes, hacks are allowed -- I think, but I'm not the arbiter on this. I was saying this is a bit of one -- not that Angular is providing much as an alternative. I appreciate the offer of another solution -- I wasn't counting anymore points against you than those against Angular.

Comment: @Cody seems interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything I tried to fix circular dependency warning with setTimeout or use of injector and moving the injection from constructor into another function didn't work for me with angular 7.

Here is my working solution:

I created another service just to hold the service referenz to first service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {

  private _service: AService;

  get service(): AService {
    return this._service;
  }
  set service(service: AService) {
    this._service = service;
  }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {

  constructor(private anotherService: AnotherService) {
    anotherService.service = this;
  }
  ...
}
```

and here:

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {
  private aService: AService;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const anotherService = injector.get(AnotherService);
    this.aService = anotherService.service;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into **circular dependency problems**, found many answers and the best way I found to solve it is following.

As far as I understood, the problem occurs when you try to pass `a: A` to `b: B` **into the constructor**. So the way to **avoid it is to create your object, and then only set `a` into `b`**

As for me A and B are not so self talking, my example will be with my case which was having

Note that the **imports do not influence** the circular dependency problem.

### rabbit.component.ts

```
export class RabbitComponent {

    public rabbitsArray: Rabbit[] = []

    constructor(){
        let lRabbit: Rabbit = new Rabbit(God.rabbitMotherFromEve())
        lRabbit.setRabbitComponent(this)
        rabbits.push(lRabbit)
    }
}
```

### rabbit.ts

```
export class Rabbit {
    public feetsArray: Foot[] // I know its not the best practices but more concise for example
    public rabbitComponent: RabbitComponent

    constructor (anyThingYouWantButRabbitComponent: RabbitMother){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue when querying my API. `A` can have many `B`s, `B` has one `A` parent. When setting up these models one of these relations need to be left out in order to avoid a circular dependency. Then, when you query you can simply cast the type as `any`:

```
this.repositoryService.Query<A>(`$filter=Id eq ${B.AId}`).subscribe(As=>this.importantProp = (As[0] as any).C.property;)
```

Then in your definition of A:

```
@JsonProperty('B', [Object], true) Bs = new Array<Object>();
@JsonProperty('C', [Object], true) C = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use interfaces - this is a common pattern in many languages.

See Günters answer

[Circular dependency with Angular 2 and SystemJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278806/circular-dependency-with-angular-2-and-systemjs)

Comment: I downvoted as linking to other answers rather than providing an answer directly is against the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

you can try to call NEW on one of the services if not having a singleton is acceptable. like

```
this._sessionService = new TempService(this);
```

This was the approach I took since neither service used undefined member variables.

Comment: Good. You mean, if you don't need it to be `@Injectable` -- if its a very static object/class.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as it removes the whole point of DI, such as test ability.

Comment: Agreed with @YahyaUddin. Defeats the whole purpose of injectable services