# Test Services in Angular 4 which as setTimeout

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service in which has some dependency injected using the `Injector` (I have inherited this code and cant change the initialization for now) using `setTimeout`

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
router:Router;
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        debugger;
        this.router = injector.get(Router);
      });
    }

    public myMethod(){
      const someString = this.router.url.slice(1,someLength);
    }
}
```

I need to test `myMethod` but when Ever I test this the `setTimeout` is called after the `TestInExecution-> mymethod` is called and gives an error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` as `Router` is not instantiated.

How to make sure that the router is injected properly before executing the test.

```
fit('Test My Service', fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location, MyService],
    (_router: Router, _location: Location, myService: MyService) => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
        //Wait for component to Initialize
        tick(500);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            _router.navigate(['/someCompoenet']).then(() => {
                expect(myService.myMethod()).toBe('Some String');
            });
        });
    })));
```

Comment: Why are you using a timeout to inject a router in your service?

Comment: There is a circular dependency , which is resolved by using `injector` and `setTimeout`. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807414/756987

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-routed-component) they use stubs to swap out the router. Could you not do that?

check out testing/router-stubs.ts [here](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/app-specs.eplnkr.html)