# Error when accessing static properties when services include each other

Tags: angular, typescript

When running the following code as-is, it get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TYPE_CAMPAIGN' of undefined`

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5j0f6Nf51kkegjnPVsa?p=preview)

entity.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CampaignService} from './campaign/campaign.service';
import {TagService} from './tag/tag.service';

@Injectable()
export class EntityService {
  static TYPES = [
    CampaignService.TYPE_CAMPAIGN,
    TagService.TYPE_TAG
  ];
}
```

campaign.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {EntityService} from '../entity.service';

@Injectable()
export class CampaignService {
  static TYPE_CAMPAIGN = 'campaign';

  constructor(private entityService: EntityService) {}

  public getTypes() {
    return EntityService.TYPES;
  }
}
```

tag.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {EntityService} from '../entity.service';

@Injectable()
export class TagService {
  static TYPE_TAG = 'tag';

  constructor(private entityService: EntityService) {}
}
```

However, when I remove the constructor from `campaign.service.ts`, the code works without issue. Why does the error occur, and how do I access static properties when the constructor is included?

**Update 1:** After testing using Angular's Injector to offset when classes are loaded, I find that I still have an issue accessing static properties of EntityService inside methods of CampaignService. I've also found that adding `private entityService: EntityService` in `campaign.service.ts` causes the issue.

**Update 2:** The issue is caused by the order of import statements in the Module that is providing the services (I recently alphabetized my import statements).

app.module.ts

```
import {CampaignService} from './campaign/campaign.service';
import {EntityService} from '../entity.service';
import {TagService} from './tag/tag.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    CampaignService,
    EntityService,
    TagService
  ]
});
```

When the import statement for `entity.service.ts` is moved before `campaign.service.ts`, both CampaignService and TagService are able to work without issue.

**Update 3:** It looks like the issue is version specific. Here is the example of the issue happening in the version I am currently using: [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5j0f6Nf51kkegjnPVsa?p=preview)

If you switch the import statements in `src/app.component.ts` while watching the console, then you will see the issue at hand.

Comment: Excellent work, that's a unique problem and difficult to pin down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be the injector decides there's a circular reference. Looking at the code, I would not expect it since only one service has a constructor. However, the behavior you describe points to this.

You can try injecting the injector and delaying the injection process by a tick.
See [Angular2: 2 services depending on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378751/angular2-2-services-depending-on-each-other)

```js
@Injectable()
export class CampaignService {
  static TYPE_CAMPAIGN = 'campaign';
  private entityService;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    setTimeout(() => this.entityService = injector.get(EntityService));
  }
}
```

---

### Using EntityService.TYPES inside campaign.service.ts

Hopefully this covers your use-case.
Here's my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpm8rt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**campaign.service.ts**

```js
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {EntityService} from './entity.service';

@Injectable()
export class CampaignService {
  static TYPE_CAMPAIGN = 'campaign';
  private entityService;
  types = EntityService.TYPES;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    setTimeout( () => this.entityService = injector.get(EntityService) );
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {EntityService} from './entity.service';
import {CampaignService} from './campaign.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  types = EntityService.TYPES;

  constructor(
    private entityService: EntityService, 
    private campaignService: CampaignService
  ) { }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```js
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div> Types from EntityService {{ types }} </div>
<div> Types from campaignService {{ campaignService.types }} </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure it has something to do with circular references, but this one is throwing me through a loop. The Injector strategy does allow me to use methods/properties inside EntityService, as long as they are not static properties. This means I still have the same issue when I try `EntityService.TYPES` inside `campaign.service.ts`.

Comment: I have a StackBlitz testbed, will see if I can get my head around it - I don't often use statics! :)

Comment: So far I have `types = EntityService.TYPES;` in app.component.ts, and it prints both types to the template.

Comment: Wow, I just found what is causing the issue... I alphabetized my import statements in the first instance I imported EntityService and CampaignService into a Module.

Comment: I would still love to know how to not have this issue in the future, aside from a general restructuring of the application. Its strange that the import order matters in this case...

Comment: I have to say, alphabetizing doesn't sound like a remedy.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a fork of the stackblitz please. Would like to check it out.

Comment: So, I think the injecting has nothing to do with it (I just removed all that injector stuff and it still works). Since the types are all static, best guess is you just had a bum reference in the import. Alphabetizing them has just led you to tidy them up.

Comment: The issues looks to be version specific. Unfortunately I am tied to an older version of Angular for the time being. I attached the example to the main question.