# service that builds components

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm getting a `circular dependency` error on my `@ComponentBuilderService` service, because some of the components that I'm importing in ie.`BreakComponent`,`LocationComponent` use this service and also import this `@ComponentBuilderService`.

What I'm trying to do is use the `buildComponents()` method inside this `@ComponentBuilderService` to be able to dynamically create components, the problem is some of the components need to use this `buildComponents()` method on this same service to build their sub-components.

**@ComponentBuilderService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentBuilderService {
    private renderer: Renderer2;
    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, renderFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = renderFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
    buildComponents(nContainer: ViewContainerRef , elements) {
        // loop through elements creating different components based on element.Type
        elements.forEach((element, idx) => {
            switch (element.Type) {
                case 'break':
                    const breakComponent = nContainer.createComponent(this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BreakComponent));
                    console.log(breakComponent.location.nativeElement);
                    break;
                case 'location':
                    const locationComponent = nContainer.createComponent(this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LocationComponent));
                    locationComponent.instance.Elements = element.Elements;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**@LocationComponent:**

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentBuilder } from '../../../shared/services/component-build.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'location',
  template: `<div> some location building </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./location.component.scss'],
})
export class LocationComponent implements  AfterContentInit {
    Elements;
    constructor(private componentBuilder: ComponentBuilder) { }
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.Elements);
        this.componentBuilder.buildComponents(this.Elements);
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there anyway to create a `ComponentBuilderService`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807414/2227788). I recall having a `circular dependency` issue once before and I remember resolving it using the `Injector` somehow, as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: How your elements model looks like? Can you share how you create your dynamic child (sub) components?