# Not running into circular dependency error with actions when using Redux in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, redux, ngrx

We are developing components for an app with Angular 5 and ngrx. Each entity (e.g. `Menu`, `List`, `Config`) consists of

- Component (`*.html`, `*.scss`, `*.ts`)
- Action (`*.ts`, Injectable)
- Reducer (`*.js`)
- plus Spec-files

except for entities without a view (e.g. Config), which do not have a component.

We have an *Config-Action* and *Config-Reducer* with which we store the options the user selects in the Menu. Because some Actions depend on each other, I recently ran into a circular-dependency-error:

1. Clicking on an item in the `Menu` calls a *List-Action* (which shows a List to the user)
2. Selecting an item from the `List` calls a *Config-Action* (to store the selection)
3. The *Config-Action* calls a *Menu-Action* (to write the selection into a field in the menu)

There is our circular dependency and it won't be the last on the Redux-"Call actions to do stuff"-approach. I'm trying to handle it with [Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807414/2725515) but this seems like a workaround. I'm looking for a solution which is more clean, as the Actions are not called in the constructor.

**Is there a clean way to inject Actions into one another without creating a circular dependency?**