# Angular CLI: False positive circular dependency warning for nested Material Dialogs?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cli, circular-dependency

My Angular 8 app uses a service class that wraps the Angular Material dialog implementation and renders dialogs, based on a number of different component types. Here's a simplified version of it:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    renderDialogTypeOne() {
        // implementation here calls
        // matDialog.open(TypeOne)
    }

    renderDialogTypeTwo() {
        // implementation here calls
        // matDialog.open(TypeTwo)
    }
}
```

Since this service class references the types that it renders, it has a dependency on them. However, one of the rendered types (`TypeTwo` below) also has the above service injected into its constructor, in order that it can launch its own dialogs of `TypeOne`:

```
export class TypeOne {
}

export class TypeTwo {
    contructor(private service: MyService) { }

    showNestedDialog() {
        this.service.renderDialogTypeOne();
    }
}
```

As a result, it appears that there is a circular dependency between the service class and `TypeTwo`. I understand that I could resolve this by separating the service class into multiple parts and only referencing the parts that are required in a given context, but it doesn't seem right to split a class purely to solve a compiler warning.

Is this really a circular dependency? If so, doesn't the same problem exist in many other scenarios, where two entities have a chicken / egg relationship?

Is there any reasonable solution, other than disabling Angular's circular dependency warnings?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way of reasoning about it without extra details. Generally, a circular dependency issue means your architecture can be improved. Elements requiring each other can generally be rearranged so they both have a common requirement. For example, in your implementation, could `renderDialogTypeTwo` pass `renderDialogTypeOne` to the new dialog instance?

Comment: Circular dependency error protects you from spagheti code. Yes, I have bumped also into this and rewriting your app in a consistent way will help you a lot. Why not extending your dialog types from a parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular Material source code for [`Dialog`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/6275b49aecf95bffbbea61cb10b3e7c8b037d6de/src/cdk-experimental/dialog/dialog.ts#L48) shows that an `Injector` is used to instantiate the Component to be displayed in the Dialog. [This approach breaks circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807414/1164465).

Therefore, the circular dependency warning appears to be a false positive.

Circular dependency warnings may be disabled by updating angular.json.  Unfortunately, this option is not available per file.

#### angular.json

```
....
  "defaults": {
    ....
    "build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
  }
```

## Workaround

The solution below allows for nested calls where a `Dialog` of component type `DialogYesNoComponent` may open a `Dialog` of component type `DialogWarningComponent` and vice versa.

### Example

```
import { DialogService, DialogYesNoComponent, DialogWarningComponent } from '...'


export class TypeOne {
  constructor(private dialog_service: DialogService) { }

  showYesNoDialog() {
    const dialog_question = "Would you like to continue?";
    const dialog_ref: MatDialogRef<DialogYesNoComponent> =
      this.dialog_service.open_yes_no_dialog({
        question: dialog_question,
        title: 'Confirm', height: '300px' })
    dialog_ref.afterClosed().subscribe(
      (choice: 'yes' | 'no') => {
        if (choice === 'yes') {
          // Continue
        } else {
          // Open Nested Dialog
          this.showWarningDialog("Stopping the program.");
        }
      }
    )
  }

  showWarningDialog(warning: String) {
    ...
  }
}
```

### DialogService

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

import { DialogWarningComponent } from './dialog-warning/dialog-warning.component';
import { DialogYesNoComponent } from './dialog-yes-no/dialog-yes-no.component';

@Injectable()
export class DialogService {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public open_yes_no_dialog({ question, title = 'Confirm', yes_button_first = true,
    has_backdrop = false, height = '250px', width = '350px' }:
    {
      question: string, title?: string, yes_button_first?: boolean, has_backdrop?: boolean,
      height?: string, width?: string
    }): MatDialogRef<DialogYesNoComponent> {

    const dialog_ref = this.dialog.open(DialogYesNoComponent, {
      autoFocus: true,
      backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
      closeOnNavigation: true,
      disableClose: false,
      hasBackdrop: has_backdrop,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      data: { question: question, title: title, yes_button_first: yes_button_first }
    })

    return dialog_ref
  }

  public open_warning_dialog() {
    { warning, title = 'Warning',
    has_backdrop = false, height = '250px', width = '350px' }:
    {
      warning: string, title?: string, has_backdrop?: boolean,
      height?: string, width?: string
    }): MatDialogRef<DialogWarningComponent> {

    const dialog_ref = this.dialog.open(DialogWarningComponent, {
      autoFocus: true,
      backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
      closeOnNavigation: true,
      disableClose: false,
      hasBackdrop: has_backdrop,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      data: { warning: warning, title: title }
    })

    return dialog_ref
  }
}
```

### DialogYesNoComponent

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';


export interface YesNoDialogOptions {
  question: string
  title: string
  yes_button_first: boolean
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-yes-no',
  templateUrl: './dialog-yes-no.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-yes-no.component.css']
})
export class DialogYesNoComponent {
  constructor(public dialog_ref: MatDialogRef<DialogYesNoComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public options: YesNoDialogOptions) { }
}
```

### DialogWarningComponent

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';


export interface WarningDialogOptions {
  warning: string
  title: string
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-warning',
  templateUrl: './dialog-warning.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-warning.component.css']
})
export class DialogWarningComponent {
  constructor(public dialog_ref: MatDialogRef<DialogWarningComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public options: WarningDialogOptions) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. From what I can see, your approach is very similar to mine, except that your service only currently supports one component type. If you wanted to add support for a second component type that needs to launch its own (nested) instances of DialogYesNoComponent, I think it would need a reference to DialogService. Wouldn't you then have the same problem as I do?

Comment: no, the goal is simply that one dialog is able to launch the other in a nested (stacked) manner. For example, dialog A may launch dialog B to collect supplementary input. In your amended example, if you wanted to achieve this behaviour, I think you would need to extend the constructor of either DialogYesNoComponent or DialogWarningComponent to accept an injected DialogService, and this is where the circular dependency occurs.

Comment: @TimCoulter See updated example, where `showYesNoDialog()` calls `showWarningDialog()` and avoids a circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherPeisert - that certainly seems to solve the problem. Very clever :) !