# how to solve circular dependency beside using interface in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, circular-dependency

Component A

```
age = 5;

updateAge(){
    this.age++;
}

openpopup(){
    this.window.open({
        title:info,
        content: B_Component
    })
}
```

Component B

```
constructor(private a: A_Compoennt){

}
clickButton(){
    this.a.updateAge();
}
```

I have two component, component A and component B, there is no parent/child relationship between those two. There is a circular dependency problem  between those two component. How do I solve this question without interface. When i check online, all the post says that use interface to resolve circular dependency.

Comment: What specific problem are you having with it? Circular dependencies aren't, in and of themselves, a problem. Separately, I'm afraid the above is too fragmentary for us to be able to help you with. Please update the question with a moer thorough description of the problem, and a [mcre] demonstrating it.

Comment: What about the use of a service?  Why would you inject a component into another component's constructor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Services depending on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378751/services-depending-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing can be done easily with a shared service. A service which is common to both the components. you can use the `getAge()` method to in case if you want to retrieve the value of `age` and it will resolve your circular dependency issue. Take a look at the below code snippets:

**common.service.ts**

```
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
  export class CommonService {
      age = 5;

   updateAge(){
    this.age++;
      }

   getAge(){
    return this.age;
      }
    }
```

**ComponentA:**

```
    export class ComponentA {
        constructor(private brodcaster: CommonService){          
         this.brodcaster.updateAge();
        }
}
```

**ComponentB:**

```
    export class ComponentA {
        constructor(private brodcaster: CommonService){
         this.brodcaster.updateAge();
        }
}
```