# Tests crashing with "Can't resolve all parameters for" for valid providers

Tags: angular, typescript

Part of service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHelper {
  constructor(private schemaValidator: SchemaValidator, private translate: TranslateService) {
  }
```

Test:

```
class TranslateServiceMock {

}

describe('ErrorHelper', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: SchemaValidator, useValue: {}},
        {provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceMock},
        ErrorHelper
      ]
    });
  });

  it('is injected', async(inject([ErrorHelper], (errorHelper: ErrorHelper) => {
    expect(errorHelper).toBeDefined();
  })));
});
```

Error:

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorHelper: (?, TranslateService).
```

I don't get it. How it can fail on DI when it doesn't even have to use real classes (I have supplied all dependencies)?

I have a few similar tests and DI works fine in them, I am really confused about this error.

If I remove `ErrorHelper` and its injection, that SchemaValidator mock is is being injected to tests just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you're importing service directly from it's own file?

Comment: If you mean importing `SchemaValidator` in `ErrorHelper` then I am importing it like this: `import { SchemaValidator } from './schema-validator.service';`. The validator is also being injected in its own tests and works, not sure why it fails in this case.

Comment: Can you improve this plunker to reproduce your problem? https://plnkr.co/edit/K4pcGI1EIVaSBDEMiXH4?p=preview

Comment: I mean that your `SchemaValidator` might be imported from different file I usually solve this kind of problem by deep debugging. If you have a github repo it would be great

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the code and I am unable to reproduce the problem in that plunk :-(. I am using webpack (slightly modified this seed - https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/), maybe it's linked to some problem in a building process? I'll try to look at compiled test files. Nevertheless thank you for your time.

Comment: I am starting to think there is some circular import issue in ErrorHelper file, I'll split it to multiple files and hope for the best.

Comment: Check also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826073/pass-parameter-to-mddialog-in-angular-material-2/40828423#40828423

Comment: One more solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525850/circular-dependency-injection-angular-2/40525992#40525992